# MySQL delete request not working

Tags: php, mysql

Anyone got any idea why out of these two mySQL requests, the first one works and the second one does not?

```
$bdd->exec('UPDATE users SET status = \'registered\' WHERE username="' . $userz . '"'); // working:)



$bdd->exec('DELETE ' . $_SESSION['prenom'] . 'friendlist WHERE name="' .  $_POST['deletefriend'] . '"'); // not working :(
```

There is no error displayed but the data does not get deleted in the database.

Comment: where is DELETE FROM ????

Comment: The syntaxe for a delete is `DELETE FROM your_table WHERE your_condition`

Comment: please post the resultant SQL query. thanks.

Comment: Does the MySQL user the script connects through have the DELETE privilege?

Comment: This is a syntax error. The correct syntax is: `DELETE FROM tbl WHERE ...`

Comment: The resultant is :

            $bdd->exec('DELETE FROM "' . $_SESSION['prenom'] . 'friendlist" WHERE name="' .  $_POST['deletefriend'] . '"');   but it still won't work graahhhhh!!!!!!!

Comment: besides all the syntax that has been mentioned... make sure your $_SESSION and $_POST variables actually have the exact data you're expecting. For example, periods "." will become underscores "_"

Comment: Wow I didint knew that I have to prevent user from having period in their  usernames

Comment: $bdd->exec("DELETE FROM ". $_SESSION['prenom'] . "friendlist WHERE friendname='".$_POST['deletefriend']."'");  // working :) I knew I readed something about small cote and big cote last year and now I know what it was... double cote  are apparantly needed to include a variable in a database name after a FROM in a delete query!!!! I think...cus it work this way and not with the small cote

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like

```
$bdd->exec('DELETE FROM `' . $_SESSION['prenom'] . 'friendlist` WHERE name="' .  mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['deletefriend']) . '"');
```

or like
**It will work**

```
$bdd->exec("DELETE FROM ". $_SESSION['prenom'] . "friendlist WHERE friendname='".$_POST['deletefriend']."'");
```

Delete From table_name .... will be the syntax for that

Comment: I'm not sure that `$_SESSION['prenom']` will handle the name of the table...

Comment: You should escape that `$_POST` variable...

Comment: I think that it sholud be either prefix of the table based on session or table name

Comment: possible.. little weird

Comment: Not working... what the difference between those ' and those ` ?

Comment: Now see I have escaped the post variable and I have qouted with `` to represent the table name

Comment: @LordDoomer, it's not the backticks (`\``) that matter. It's the `FROM` part that matters.

Comment: I seen that, but it's not working, I can update that same table without escaping the variable and it works. Only the delete wont work. I guess I'll just use some friendstate blocked to hide em from the friendlist :(

Comment: Still would have been nice to delete entry from database without going into myadmin...

Comment: how do I escape a variable anyways ? with backslash ? like when I escape a character ?

Comment: Will you able to delete from database by executing the same query without FROM..??

Comment: I don't think so, but my update query work in that same database with my same concatened database name. Maybe the from won't take variable in the name but that would be weird...

Comment: Can you echo the post variable before you execute the DELETE statement..??

Comment: This one work fine:        $bdd->exec('UPDATE ' . $_SESSION['prenom'] . 'friendlist SET friendstate=\'blocked\' WHERE friendname="' . $_POST['deletefriend'] . '"');

Comment: Once try my edit...plz

Comment: both failed sorry :(   Man I wish I did not have to come here and bug you all guys everytime I get stuck and thank you very much everyone for your time and help

Comment: why is the $_SESSION['prenom'] var should be escaped anyway it is not after an = and there are no cote around database name after a FROM in other working query I made like this one : $req = $bdd->prepare('SELECT username, status, activation FROM users');

Comment: It escapes the following characters:
\0
\n
\r
\
'
"
\Z

Comment: I'm pretty sure the database name after FROM does not need cotes, but it won't work with or without em, it won't even work with a normal database base name with no variable in it :(

Comment: I got it I got it!!!!!!!!! like this  it's working wow I'm so good I did it almost by myself if we forget the synthax part :)  it's like this :           $bdd->exec("DELETE FROM ". $_SESSION['prenom'] . "friendlist WHERE friendname='".$_POST['deletefriend']."'");                         apparently the double cote need to have the single cote inside them and I knew that the variable in the database name after FROM did not need any cote look look it's working!!!! yessssssss

Comment: Same as my ans only you changed the quotes..thats it

Comment: Yes we also proud to found your own ans for your own question,and we can proud much if you solve your all questions on your own without any help of us

Comment: Please put this line into your post so I can mark this thread as solved as I cannot answer my own post for another 7 hours here is the working line of code:    $bdd->exec("DELETE FROM ". $_SESSION['prenom'] . "friendlist WHERE friendname='".$_POST['deletefriend']."'");